# Selenium Test Reporting: XSLT reporting OR ExtentReports

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, test-report

Actually, I'm currently working on test automation to a project. I'm using Selenium Webdriver (Java) and TestNG. I have adapted page-object model in my coding and have integrated excel functionality to save test data on it.

Now, I want to integrate a test reporting to my test automation(cause it says that "test automation without reporting is nothing"). I know there's already a default reporting in TestNG.

But what I want to know is: what third-party test reporting should I use, `XSLT` or `ExtentReports`. What's the advantage of using the other one? Or should I start first using former and then proceed to the latter or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

[image][image: EXTENT REPORT]

**Extent Report** is much better than XSLT Report.

In Extent Report, All information like who run the test when this test got passed, how much time does it took to get completed.

Major **feature** is the **rich GUI** it possess.

Also all the relevant details to the corresponding test can be provided make it pretty more easy for the person who is having a look into it.

A dashboard is there to view all these details in a single shell.

Apart from that its an opensource and can manage it pretty easily by a few lines of code.

I have been using several reports but now I felt confident with extent report as the person who looks into it should get a better feeling. Whatever be its result but he/she should get a vision to have look into it for a minute atleast. In that case it is very good.

Go with Extent Reports. you can download it from **http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/**

It supports both java and .net.

Answer (score 0):

I guess ExtentReports re more interactive than all others.
The 1st impression on the test report will be fantastic for the reader(Client or Project manager).

As i believe 1st impression is the most important thing for any thing.

But on ExtentReports you have to do some extra codding by adding notes, steps and pass fail status.
But i think it is worth doing it.